# Voice channel userlimit discord js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a voice channel with ***Discord Bot***
. This is my code simply (I'm using discord.js)

```
message.channel.createChannel('General', "voice").then(chan => {
    chan.userLimit("5");
})
```

But the console log is like that

```
(node:13080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.channel.createChannel is not a function
```

How can I handle of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the `.createChannel` method on a channel, you need to use it on a guild.

This would be correct:
discord.js v11

```js
message.guild.createChannel();
```

discord.js v12

```js
message.guild.channels.create();
```

Comment: Yeah after u wrote I realized, I made mistake there. However code still doesn't working correctly. It creates a channel but it can't make a userlimit on it :/

Comment: What do you mean with userlimit? Take a look at: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel . There is everything you need to know :) I would be happy if you would mark my answer as correct because it solved your error that you mentioned in your question